# List of vectors multiplied by one matrix with numpy einsum

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3x3 matrix and I would like to multiply each vector in a list by this matrix.

This can be done easily with a loop:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0,1,0],[-1,0,0],[0,0,1]])
b = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])

for elem in b:
   print(a.dot(elem))
```

To make it quicker I have tried using numpy.einsum but I am not able to do the correct formulation.

I have tried  `np.einsum('ij,ji->ij', a, b)` but this results in `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (3,3)->(3,3) (2,3)->(3,2)`

Any advice ?

Comment: Why not simply `a @ b.T` (`@` is same as `.dot`) No need for fancy `einsum` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [489]: for elem in b:
     ...:     print(a.dot(elem))
     ...:     
[ 2 -1  3]
[ 5 -4  6]
```

first step - you are iterating the first dimension of `b`, and expecting that in the result as well:

```
np.einsum(',i->i', a, b)
```

`dot` pairs the last dim of `a` with the only dim of elem, the 2nd dim of `b` - and sums them:

```
np.einsum(' j,ij->i', a, b)
```

Now fill in the first dimension of `a`, which passes through as the last dim of the result:

```
In [495]: np.einsum('kj,ij->ik', a, b)
Out[495]: 
array([[ 2, -1,  3],
       [ 5, -4,  6]])
```

Switch the arguments around, and a regular 2d dot product appears:

```
In [496]: np.einsum('ij,kj->ik', b, a)
Out[496]: 
array([[ 2, -1,  3],
       [ 5, -4,  6]])
In [497]: b.dot(a.T)    # b@(a.T)
Out[497]: 
array([[ 2, -1,  3],
       [ 5, -4,  6]])
```